# Python - Getting Attributes From A File of Constants

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file of constant variables that I need to query and I am not sure how to go about it. 
I have a database query which is returning user names and I need to find the matching user name in the file of constant variables.

The file looks like this:

```
SALES_MANAGER_01 = {"user_name": "BO01", "password": "password", "attend_password": "BO001",
                    "csm_password": "SM001", "employee_num": "BOSM001"}
```

There is just a bunch of users just like the one above.
My function looks like this:

```
@attr("user_test")
def test_get_user_for_login(self):
    application_code = 'BO'
    user_from_view = self.select_user_for_login(application_code=application_code)
    users = [d['USER'] for d in user_from_view]
    user_with_ent = choice(users)
    user_wo_ent = user_with_ent[-4:]
    password = ""
    global_users = dir(gum)
    for item in global_users:
        if user_wo_ent not in item.__getattr__("user_name"):
            user_with_ent = choice(users)
            user_wo_ent = user_with_ent[-4:]
        else:
            password = item.__getattr__("password")
    print(user_wo_ent, password)
```

`global_users = dir(gum)` is my file of constants. So I know I am doing something wrong since I am getting an attribute error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`, I am just not sure how to go about resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse your looping as you want to compare each `item` to your match condition. Also, you have a dictionary, so use it to do some heavy lifting.

You need to add some imports

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
```

I've changed the `dir(gum)` bit to be this function.

```
def get_global_users(filename):
    gusers = {}  # create a global users dict
    p_key = re.compile(ur'\b\w*\b') # regex to get first part, e.g.. SALES_MANAGER_01
    p_value = re.compile(ur'\{.*\}') # regex to grab everything in {}
    with (open(filename)) as f: # open the file and work through it
        for line in f: # for each line
            gum_key = p_key.match(line) # pull out the key
            gum_value = p_value.search(line) # pull out the value
            ''' Here is the real action. update a dictionary
            with the match of gum_key and with match of gum_value'''
            gusers[gum_key.group()] = literal_eval(gum_value.group())
    return(gusers) # return the dictionary
```

The bottom of your existing code is replaced with this.

```
global_users = get_global_users(gum) # assign return to global_users
for key, value in global_users.iteritems(): # walk through all key, value pairs
    if value['user_name'] != user_wo_ent:
        user_with_ent = choice(users)
        user_wo_ent = user_with_ent[-4:]
    else:
        password = value['password']
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` since the `dir(gum)` line is only returning the constant names not the values.

Comment: Thank you @ShawnMehan this looks like it will work. Can I not put a .py file through the `get_global_users`? I am getting this error now: 
`TypeError: invalid file: <module 'env_settings.global_user_mappings' from '/Users/curtis.salisbury/Documents/qa/trunk/automation/selenium/src/env_settings/global_user_mappings.py'>`

Comment: DarthOpto, your question keeps morphing. You either need to ask a new question or edit this one. If I have answered your original question, please mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

So a very simple answer was get the `dir` of the constants file then parsing over it like so:

```
 global_users = dir(gum)
 for item in global_users:
     o = gum.__dict__[item]
     if type(o) is not dict:
         continue
     if gum.__dict__[item].get("user_name") == user_wo_ent:
         print(user_wo_ent, o.get("password"))
     else:
         print("User was not in global_user_mappings")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer by doing the following:

```
def get_user_for_login(application_code='BO'):
user_from_view = BaseServiceTest().select_user_for_login(application_code=application_code)
users = [d['USER'] for d in user_from_view]
user_with_ent = choice(users)
user_wo_ent = user_with_ent[4:]
global_users = dir(gum)
user_dict = {'user_name': '', 'password': ''}
for item in global_users:
    o = gum.__dict__[item]
    if type(o) is not dict:
        continue
    if user_wo_ent == o.get("user_name"):
        user_dict['user_name'] = user_wo_ent
        user_dict['password'] = o.get("password")
return user_dict
```